# Does "Join" order will lead to different query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables (table1 table2), table2 is larger than table1.

*Script 1:*

```
SELECT t1.A, t2.B
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.PK = t2.FK
```

*Script 2:*

```
SELECT t1.A, t2.B
FROM table2 AS t2
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.PK = t2.FK
```

Does performance script #1 will be better than script #2?

Comment: `SQL Server` generate execution plan based on cost... So answer - no.

Comment: Inner joins are fully commutative and the optimiser rearranges them as it sees fit already as long as you don't have hints forcing join order.

Comment: I don't understand the upvotes on this question. It's a very easy test to do yourself - so easy I even considered a downvote.

Comment: @ZoharPeled and easily googleable with plenty of answers out there already.

Comment: @SueSu: just run both queries in SSMS and include the actual execution plan. You will see for yourself.

Comment: This one has **many** duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+join+order

Answer (score 2):

You are using an **INNER JOIN** so the answer is **NO**.

This will produce exactly the same amount of data due to the join type, and you are joining by the same relations in both queries, so they are basically identical.

It would have been different if you had used a **LEFT JOIN** , because in a left join, all the data from the master(left) table is kept, and all the matching data from the details table(right) .

So if you had used left join, and placed the larger table on the left side, then the query would have produced more data and probably would be slower then to put the larger table in the right side.

Answer (score 2):

It *should* create the same plan. But if you got lots of joins shuffling the join order might change the plan due to the enormous number of possible ways to process those joins.

See [Optimizing Join Orders](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/06/optimizing-join-orders/)

Of course this is only for Inner joins, Outer joins might return different results. Btw, the optimizer should love Outer joins, it's greatly reducing the number of possible join orders :-)

Answer (score 2):

Inner join is commutative ,what that means  a join b= b join a.Logical join may be inner join,but in execution plan sql may try to consider nested loops,hash or merge based on several parameters..None of the physical join is bad,each has its own advantages.

One thing which you can take care from your side( at bare minimum,) is try to see if both join columns are indexed,sargabilty, no implicit conversions .